# Why do so many games for PS3 have 'restricted/locked' save-games?

Tags: ps3

Many of the games I played had 'locked' save-games, so they can't be copied to an USB-Stick, for example. But I'm wondering why? Is it an agreement between Sony and the development studios to force the Playstation Plus features? What motivations have these developers to block the copying?

Personally, for me it's very uncomfortable because I have to switch between two systems.

Comment: It's also a big issue for some Xbox 360 games as well.

Answer (score 4):

Games which have copy protection often have player-unique features that prevent them from being usable by other users it could be online progress/stats (the case for Demon's Souls) and I believe sometimes it's because some saves include DLC data that might be problematic when transferred between users who don't own it (I believe that's the reason for Dragon Age's saves being copy protected).

Personally I think a solution where a save is transferable but only usable by the original PSN ID is the best, however I think Sony's afraid users would modify those saves and copy them back, if you look at Borderlands, for example, where the saves aren't copy protected, item hacking and duping is abundant.

I agree with you on the comfort issue, I myself lost a few copy protected saves lately because a backup went wrong and I only had backups of my non-protected saves I copied before.

Comment: I lost a _Fable II_ hero in a similar way. Devs flip the `nocopy` bit when they don't want players to "cheat" by loading a prior save file. But it is to the detriment of the user base as is prevents players from backing up game saves and they risk loosing it all.

Comment: They need to come up with a better solution.  My PS3 just died, and my hundreds of hours of game play are lost because I can't load them onto the used system that I just purchased.  And no, I couldn't use the PS3's transfer utility because the old system won't stay powered on long enough to do that.